# Remove .csv and .txt files

Tags: find

The following command is working as expected...

```
find /var/lib/mysql -name "*.csv" -or -name "*.txt" -or -name "*.text" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

It will remove the csv or txt file found in the data directory.
Just wanted to make sure if the syntax is correct and this is the best way to achive the results.

Comment: If the command works as you want it to, it looks good to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're worried about running it on a directory full of precious files, just create a test directory with test files and try the `find` on your test files. If that works, run it on your real data.